Модальное окно не появляется после успешной проверки в процессе регистрации
Я разрабатываю экран регистрации на React Native, где использую react-native-modal для отображения двух разных модальных окон:

Модальное окно для проверки электронной почты, которое появляется после начала процесса регистрации.
Модальное окно успешного завершения, которое должно появиться после завершения проверки электронной почты.

Модальное окно проверки работает как ожидается, но модальное окно успешной верификации не появляется после успешной проверки. Я попытался вызвать его с помощью события onModalHide, но оно так и не отображается.
const [showSuccessModal, setShowSuccessModal] = useState(false);

// Модальное окно проверки
<ReactNativeModal
  isVisible={verification.state === "pending"}
  onModalHide={() => {
    if (verification.state === "success") setShowSuccessModal(true);
  }}
>
  {/* Содержимое модального окна проверки */}
</ReactNativeModal>

// Модальное окно успешного завершения
<ReactNativeModal isVisible={showSuccessModal}>
  {/* Содержимое модального окна успешного завершения */}
</ReactNativeModal>

На всякий случай вот полный код экрана
import { useSignUp } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import { Link, router } from "expo-router";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Alert, Image, ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { ReactNativeModal } from "react-native-modal";

import CustomButton from "@/components/CustomButton";
import InputField from "@/components/InputField";
import OAuth from "@/components/OAuth";
import { icons, images } from "@/constants";

const SignUp = () => {
  const { isLoaded, signUp, setActive } = useSignUp();
  const [showSuccessModal, setShowSuccessModal] = useState(false);

  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [verification, setVerification] = useState({
    state: "default",
    error: "",
    code: "",
  });

  const onSignUpPress = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await signUp.create({
        emailAddress: form.email,
        password: form.password,
      });

      await signUp.prepareEmailAddressVerification({ strategy: "email_code" });

      setVerification({
        ...verification,
        state: "pending",
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      Alert.alert("Error", err.errors[0].longMessage);
    }
  };

  const onPressVerify = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const completeSignUp = await signUp.attemptEmailAddressVerification({
        code: verification.code,
      });

      if (completeSignUp.status === "complete") {
        await setActive({ session: completeSignUp.createdSessionId });
        setVerification({ ...verification, state: "success" });
      } else {
        setVerification({
          ...verification,
          error: "Verification failed",
          state: "failed",
        });
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      setVerification({
        ...verification,
        error: err.errors[0].longMessage,
        state: "failed",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView className="flex-1 bg-white">
      <View className="flex-1 bg-white">
        <View className="relative w-full h-[250px]">
          <Image source={images.signUpCar} className="z-0 w-full h-[250px]" />
          <Text className="text-2xl text-black font-JakartaSemiBold absolute bottom-5 left-5">
            Create Your Account
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View className="p-5">
          <InputField
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            icon={icons.person}
            value={form.name}
            onChangeText={(value) => setForm({ ...form, name: value })}
          />
          <InputField
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            icon={icons.email}
            textContentType="emailAddress"
            value={form.email}
            onChangeText={(value) => setForm({ ...form, email: value })}
          />
          <InputField
            label="Password"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            icon={icons.lock}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            textContentType="password"
            value={form.password}
            onChangeText={(value) => setForm({ ...form, password: value })}
          />
          <CustomButton
            title="Sign Up"
            onPress={onSignUpPress}
            className="mt-6"
          />
          <OAuth />
          <Link
            href="/sign-in"
            className="text-lg text-center text-general-200 mt-10"
          >
            Already have an account?{" "}
            <Text className="text-primary-500">Log In</Text>
          </Link>
        </View>

        <ReactNativeModal
          isVisible={verification.state === "pending"}
          onModalHide={() => {
            if (verification.state === "success") setShowSuccessModal(true);
          }}
        >
          <View className="bg-white px-7 py-9 rounded-2xl min-h-[300px]">
            <Text className="text-2xl font-JakartaExtraBold mb-2">
              Verification
            </Text>
            <Text className="font-Jakarta mb-5">
              We've sent a verification code to {form.email}
            </Text>
            <InputField
              label="code"
              icon={icons.lock}
              placeholder="1234"
              value={verification.code}
              keyboardType="numeric"
              onChangeText={(code) =>
                setVerification({ ...verification, code })
              }
            />
            {verification.error && (
              <Text className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">
                {verification.error}
              </Text>
            )}

            <CustomButton
              title="Verify Email"
              onPress={onPressVerify}
              className="mt-5 bg-success-500"
            />
          </View>
        </ReactNativeModal>

        <ReactNativeModal isVisible={showSuccessModal}>
          <View className="bg-white px-7 py-9 rounded-2xl min-h-[300px]">
            <Image
              source={images.check}
              className="w-[110px] h-[110px] mx-auto my-5"
            />
            <Text className="text-3xl font-JakartaBold text-center">
              Verified
            </Text>
            <Text className="text-base text-gray-400 font-Jakarta text-center mt-2">
              You have successfully verified your account.
            </Text>
            <CustomButton
              title="Browse Home"
              onPress={() => router.replace("/(root)/(tabs)/home")}
              className="mt-5"
            ></CustomButton>
          </View>
        </ReactNativeModal>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
export default SignUp;

